# How to increase height of 'band' element if the value in 'textFieldExpression' has greater height than the height specified in "band height"?

Tags: jasper-reports

My detail element is as follows:-

```
<detail>
    <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement uuid="a59a8d47-59cb-490e-953d-d4b1e2af52c0" x="0" y="0" width="191" height="20"/>
            <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="ARIALUNI" size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{key}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement uuid="09798815-2a54-42db-963a-3f443a5fc1c2" x="191" y="0" width="500" height="20"/>
            <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="ARIALUNI" size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

If I set band height="30", then the value of second   correctly overflows but at same time extra white space is visible for rows where there is no overflow. With band height="22", no extra whitespace and also no overflows (which is a requirement). So can the height of band be set dynamically so that height increases when overflow takes place, otherwise it (height) maintains a low value (without extra-space).

Answer (score 0):

This already happens automatically. If a band contains content that stretches, it will also stretch to accommodate that content. Or, as the [*JasperReports Ultimate Guide*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) puts it:

> "When stretchable text fields are present on a report section, the height of the report section
>   itself is affected by the stretch."

This makes sense when you think about when the report is filled. Theoretically you could always pass longer and longer data, making the text field stretch further and further. If the band height had to be set manually to accommodate this, you would be forever updating the design.

So what's the solution? Easy: Design everything at the minimum height, set fields to stretch if they need to, and don't worry about the band height.

#### What about the white space?

The white space you're seeing is probably due to the way space in the design is preserved at the end of a band. With your example, the band height is 22 pixels, but the content only fills a height of 20 pixels, leaving a 2 pixel row of white space at the bottom of the band. When you increase the band height to 30 pixels, without increasing the size of the content (I'm assuming this is the case), you will have created 10 pixels of white space.

The white space you leave in you design will be included in the filled report, repeated for each instance of the band and still included if the content stretches. So after your text field stretches to be 30 pixels tall, the band will stretch to 40 pixels to preserve the 10 pixels of white space.